# how to map dynamic columns from one row to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with columns:-

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="fetchData()">&nbsp;Fetch </button>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>User Id</th>
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>
                    <th>C</th>
                    <th>D</th>
                    <th>E</th>
                    <th>F</th>
                    <th>G</th>
                    <th>H</th>
                    <th>I</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in dataList track by $index" class="noFocus" ng-class="{'selected': isSelected(row.userID)}" ng-click="selectRow(row.userID)">
                  <td>{{row.userId}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.A}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.B}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.C}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.D}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.E}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.F}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.G}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.H}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.I}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

I am fetching data from one live table which display data only for A, B, E, F, G, H. So, when I select a particular row for the same userId I want to fetch other columns data C, D, I from a different table when user click FETCH button.
The details C, D, I is an array of only one object name `otherDetails` 
The data in dataList is an array of objects. So what I want is I want to add `otherDetails` in that row which I selected. 
I am trying:-

```
 scope.otherDetails.push(entry.fieldMap);
  scope.dataList.map(scope.otherDetails[0]);
```

But it is not showing the C, D, I columns. Can anyone help me how I can achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: The answer to this question can depend on a few things, for example, if the tables are bound to an array of objects, then manipulating/filtering the arrays would be the way to go. You could ID the columns with row/column names/ids and use selectors to grab them. You could assign a single style to all cells in one table, a different style to all the cells in the other table, then use selectors to grab both element collections and do your inspection/filtering that way. You need to provide some more info, but minimally, how do you build the tables, what are you doing with the backing data?